# Object Required: Name Space

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

Can anyone help me fix this error I've encountered?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as an image, try to provide a formatted code block containing a [mcve]. See [ask].

Comment: okay will do. this is my first time to post here so im not familiar on things that i should avoid.

Comment: It's likely the trailing \ on `sUnzipFileName` causing the problem, remove it. Spotted in the Watch window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBS unzipping - object required: 'objshell.NameSpace(…)'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31222255/692942)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwudW.jpg) I would guess the issue is with the `sUnzipFileName` variable containing a trailing backslash character *(value should be `REF.zip` not `REF.zip\`)* which isn't valid in a filename. This will cause the `NameSpace()` method to fail and not return an object reference which in turn means `Items` is not accessible hence the error;

> Object required: 'NameSpace(...)'

If the `CreateObject()` had been at fault you would have likely had a

> Object does not support this property or method

error instead.